# Why additional column is showing in WPF DataGrid

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am using DotNet 4.0, in my windows application UserPermissionList is binding with datagrid. This userpermission contains two columns those are manually created as DataGridTextColumn in datagrid.But Why additional empty column showing in datagrid. I have added property AutoGenerateColumns="False" even though it is not working. How to remove empty column in datagrid. Could you please help me to solve this issue?

```
<Window x:Class="DataGridSamples.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataGridSamples"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">    
    <Grid>
        <Grid Margin="5,5,15,5">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="120" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Label Grid.Column="0" Width="120" Content="User Roles:"  />

            <DockPanel Grid.Column="1">
                <Border BorderBrush="DarkGray" Background="White" BorderThickness="2">
                    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                        <DataGrid Style="{DynamicResource DGHeaderStyle}" Background="White" HeadersVisibility="All" IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                  CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" IsTextSearchEnabled="True" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserAddRows="False" 
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=UserPermissionList}" CanUserReorderColumns="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Role" Binding="{Binding Path=Role}"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Path=Description}"/>
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                        </DataGrid>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </DockPanel>


        </Grid>



<Application x:Class="DataGridSamples.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataGridSamples"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="DGHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
            <Setter Property="ColumnHeaderStyle" Value="{DynamicResource DGCHeaderStyle}"/>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="DGCHeaderStyle" TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="22"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />            
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10" />
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial" />
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `HorizontalAlignment` property of the `DataGrid` to `Left` if you don't want it to stretch horizontally:

```
<DataGrid ... HorizontalAlignment="Left">
```

Comment: <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{DynamicResource DGHeaderStyle}" Background="White" HeadersVisibility="All" IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                  CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" IsTextSearchEnabled="True" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserAddRows="False" 
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=UserPermissionList}" CanUserReorderColumns="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False">

Comment: when last column data exceeds datagrid width horizontal scrollbar is not coming?but vertical scrollbar working fine.